# Javascript arrayList with images

Tags: javascript

I am storing image tags in an ArrayList but my code doesn't work and it is pretty simple, dunno why.

```
var total_Events = [];

    var img =
         $('<img>', {
            'title': 'Title_1 (Event '+wavy_counter+')',
            'class': 'listed_event',
            'id': 'wavy_event_'+wavy_counter+'',
            'data-count': ''+wavy_counter+'',
            'src': 'final_buttons/test.png', 
            'height': '50', 
            'width': '50', 
            'onclick': 'highlight.call(this);', 
            'data-start': '', 
            'data-end': ''
        });

    img.appendTo('#event_list_main');

    //Storing Event
    store_event(img);
```

and the store_event function:

```
function store_event(event)
{
    total_Events.push(event);

};
```

When I print the array I get nothing.

EDIT: Print Code

```
$('#test').click(function()
{
    for(var i=0;i<total_Events.length;i++){
        document.write(total_Events[i]);
    }
});
```

Comment: You're going to need to post more code, and in particular the code you use to "print" the array. Also JavaScript doesn't have anything called an "ArrayList"; it's just an Array.

Comment: What do you mean by "print" in this case?

Comment: Yikes with `onclick': 'highlight.call(this);',` not good practice.

Comment: yeah I know I will add an event handler alter though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code adding the img to the array is good. Just make sure that the function `store_event` is defined before the code calling the function. And make verify that `wavy_counter` is defined.

Comment: I added the function before calling it, nothing

Comment: Found the mistake! I had the array initalization under "$(document).ready(function(){......"

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var img =
     $('<img>').attr({
        'title': 'Title_1 (Event '+wavy_counter+')',
        'class': 'listed_event',
        'id': 'wavy_event_'+wavy_counter+'',
        'data-count': ''+wavy_counter+'',
        'src': 'final_buttons/test.png', 
        'height': '50', 
        'width': '50', 
        'onclick': 'highlight.call(this);', 
        'data-start': '', 
        'data-end': ''
    });
```